# Variable dots - accessing an attribute from a class

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
from django.template import Template, Context
    class Person(object):
        def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
            self.first_name, self.last_name = first_name, last_name
t = Template('Hello, {{ person.first_name }} {{ person.last_name }}.')
c = Context({'person': Person('John', 'Smith')})
t.render(c)
>>> u'Hello, John Smith.
```

Okay, so whats confusing me is this: `{{ person.last_name }}` . Specifically, what attribute it is extracting from the class.

Since we have 3 attributes in the Person class:

```
self.first_name, self.last_name = first_name, last_name
```

Why isn't `{{ person.last_name }}` calling from `'self.last_name = first_name'` and getting an output of John. Why is `{{ person.last_name }}` instead getting `"last_name"`?

Comment: btw indentation is wrong

Answer (score 4):

So the gist of your questions seem to be this line:

```
self.first_name, self.last_name = first_name, last_name
```

This line simply assigns self.first_name from first_name and self.last_name from last_name. It is the same as this:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
```

So in Python this:

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

just means that a gets the value 1 and b get the value 2. If you wanted a and b to have the same value you would do:

```
a = b = 1
```

Comment: ...and do it _this_ way. The tuple assignment just looks like someone trying to be clever. It's certainly not more readable or easily maintainable.

Comment: Wow, I had not noticed this is what it was doing. I assumed that in python syntax a ',' meant that the line would simply mean it was being continued so I had assumed that 'self.last_name = first_name' was actually an assignment of sorts. 

Also, wouldn't the tuple assignment need to use parenthesis, like this:
(self.first_name, self.last_name )= (first_name, last_name) ? Or at least parenthesis on one side ?

Comment: 1, 2 is just syntactic sugar for (1, 2). So no, you don't need any parenthesis. Try writing 1, 2 in your interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of your assignment in init method.

```
self.first_name, self.last_name = first_name, last_name
```

Which is equal to

```
self.first_name = first_name
self.last_name = last_name
```

So whats the confusion here...?

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` has 3 variable `self`, `first_name` and `last_name`.

`self` is like `this` in other language. `first_name` and `last_name` are local variable passed to `__init__`, due to that `first_name` and `last_name` has no reference outside `__init__`.

We are storing `first_name` and `last_name` in the object variable as `self.first_name` and `self.last_name`. `self.first_name` and `self.last_name` has scope of Object life.

Assign of values are

```
self.first_name, self.last_name = first_name, last_name
```

is like

```
(self.first_name, self.last_name) = (first_name, last_name)
```

Assign 2 value of left side with 2 values of right side.